# Magento product_attribute.addOption asking for default option

Tags: magento, soap

I am using SOAP v1 of the Magento API, I am trying to add an option to an attribute. Using the following documentation [Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.addOption.html)

This is the code I am using just as a test

```
$attributeCode = "colour";
$optionToAdd = array(
    "Label" => array(
        array(
            "store_id" => 1,
            "value" => "Green"
        )
    ),
    "order" => 0,
    "is_default" => 0
);
```

When I make the call to the API it returns the following -

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [108] Default option value is not defined
```

I cannot for the life of me get this to work. There is nothing else I am missing from the docs?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it might be that you must define a value for store_id 0 (admin)? 
You only define a value for store_id 1 but it might be required to have a value in the admin.

Comment: You are right, you can't create option from backend without entering option value for admin store. API validation for attribute options is the same.

Comment: Glad it was something simple! Thank you!

Comment: Great, I just came accross the same error and your answer really helped me. I forgot to add the admin values.

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to the accepted answer. The value of store_id must be an ArrayOfStrings. So the data should look like this:

```
$attributeCode = "colour";
$optionToAdd = array(
    "label" => array(
        array(
            "store_id" => array("0","1"),
            "value" => "Green"
        )
    ),
    "order" => 0,
    "is_default" => 0
);
```